# Logout button functionality in mean stack ,how to make the session expire?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material, mean-stack

i have been working on a project as intern and is new to mean stack 
this is the issue i am facing ,
i have been asked to create a login page that is done , but the catch is the login is authenticated by the company side . So basically in my login component the following logic is what i have implemented. 
login.component.ts file’s component goes like the following

```
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('value',this.loginForm.value)

    if(this.errorMail.length === 0) {
      this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((res:any) => {
        console.log('login response', res)
        if(res.auth.success === true) {
          localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(res.auth))
          this.loginService.loggedIn$.next(res.auth)
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/search/list')
        } else {
        this.errorMail='Email or password is not valid'
        }
      })
    }
```

the following is login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

interface LoginResponse {
  success: boolean
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)
login(creds) {
    // console.log('creds',creds)
   return this.http.post<LoginResponse>('url-of-company', {creds})
  }
```

and in my header component where i have the logout button : 
the content of header.component.ts ;

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from './header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: HeaderService,public router:Router) { }
  onLogout(){
    this.authService.logout();
this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
```

the authService in above code is imported from header.service.ts and the header.service.ts goes like;

```
import { LoginService } from './../../login/login.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

interface LoginResponse {
  success: boolean
}

export class HeaderService{

  constructor(private router: Router,private http: HttpClient,private user:LoginService) {}
 logout() {
    this.http.delete<LoginResponse>('url-of-comapy');
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
```

Basically i am trying to delete the authentication creds which i am getting from the url-of-company and is redirecting it to the login page

please help me with what is wrong an where i should do the correction and what to do for logout in my scenario .

Comment: Why do you want to delete the creds from the db? And are you using jwt for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is delete the creds from `localStorage` not from the database which is what you are trying to do in the code above in `logout()` function.

You do not need the `logout()` function in `authService` and change your `onLogout()` function in `header.component.ts` to this:

```
onLogout(){
  localStorage.removeItem('auth');
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
```

Comment: i implemented the ur code but it seems to not give me the desire result :(

Comment: Then I am not sure what you are after as the first line will delete the authentication creds and the second line will navigate you to the login component as you wanted.

Comment: second line is doing it's work properly and i am getting navigated to login page , that was happening earlier as well, but the logout is not happening properly , if i click back button i am landing inside the app

Comment: localStorage.removeItem('auth');
not ending the session

Comment: You need to share more code and explain your issue a bit better.

Comment: this is all my code for login actually . when one logs in a token gets generated .